# azure ignoring saml metadata descriptors

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

We have received metadata from a large enterprise that has both IDPSSOdescriptor and SPSSOdescriptor tag. While uploading the metadata  to enterprise apps, Azure picks up the first logout settings present in the metadata, although its clearly marked as IDPSSOdescriptor tag. This can be further tested by switching the SPSSO section with the IDPSSO section. Azure ignores the tags and uploads the first logout URL it finds.

Am i doing something wrong? I have tested multiple metadata files of 3rd party apps this way, azure clearly ignores the tags and selects the first settings it finds.

Comment: If Azure AD is acting as IdP, why do you not adjust the meta data file to include the SPSSO descriptor only? The same holds true when you export Federation Metadata  from Azure AD or ADFS it includes all kind of descriptors , not only the SAML2 ones.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. But i dislike making such a manual change, Azure is supposed to automate this exact thing. 

Moreover it caused quite the confusion when we were testing and I just didn’t think that Azure would be the problem for a long time. I am curious to know how azure consumes metadata for future integrations as well.

Comment: Then you should tell the federation partner to provide the needed descriptor only. Why would you import IdP and SP when you only need one of them?